# Indesign Couple two paragraphs together

Tags: adobe-indesign, quarkxpress

everytime I have to format text, I need that feature and I cannot find it.

Situation 2 paragraphs:

```
para1

para2
```

The logic should avoid that `para1` is on `site X` and `para2` is on `site X+1`

Does it exist in indesign/quarkypress or another program?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you can use the "Keep Options" function to ensure that the two paragraphs stay together.

Select some text in the first paragraph, and then from the paragraph menu, select the three lines at the far right of your screen.
[image]

That will open a large context menu. Choose "Keep Options."
[image]

The screen that opens allows you to set specifics about how much text you want to keep together.  If you want to keep the entire second paragraph in the same text frame as the first paragraph, then you will check "Keep Lines Together" and "All Lines in Paragraph."  There are other options that you can use--I suggest you experiment to understand what they all mean.

[image]

"Keep Options" is one of the elements available in Paragraph Styles, so once you have created a setting that does what you would like it to, make sure you capture it in a paragraph setting so that you can easily format other paragraphs with the same settings.

Comment: i know that keep options but this is not exatly what I'm searching for. I want that the first paragraphs format can select that the second paragraph will never be on another site. Like your solution I have to know the first paragraphs linecount. I think indesign messed things up here. I don't know if they ever use their products in production... Is it possiblew to fix this with a script?

Comment: your solution only works on one paragraph. Or I set it on second para and have to know the linecount of the first which is pretty bad...

Comment: If you create a paragraph style including the keep options as I showed above, then you can apply that style to as many paragraphs as you want, and they will all be linked to the paragraph after them.  There is no need to set "Keep with Previous" options at all.  The way it is shown above ensure that the entirety of paragraph 2 is kept with in the same text box as the end of paragraph 1. If this does not work to solve the problem you are facing, then I don't think I really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: BTW--if you do create a style that you then apply to numerous paragraphs, pay attention to the fact that your text box must be large enough to include all of the lines of text--otherwise you will have a blank text frame with all of your text overset.

Comment: My guess is that you are misunderstanding how to set the different options in the Keep Options menu.  Here is Adobe's page that describes what each of the different options does:  https://helpx.adobe.com/indesign/using/formatting-paragraphs.html

Comment: thx I missunderstood the form.